# Build xml from winform items

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I want to fill an xml document from a winform content.
for example if my winform looks like:

Profile: *a*
Name: *abcd*
Age: *40*
Country: *China*

While Profile,Name, Age, Country are labels, and a, abcd, 40, china are textboxes.

The xml should look like:

```
<profiles>
  <profile name="a">
    <name>abcd</name>
    <age>40</age>
    <country>china</country>
  </profile>
   ...
</profiles>
```

I don't know in advance what labels/textboxes I will have, so it should all come from the winform.

I started doing things like:

```
    List<string> data= new List<string>();
    foreach (Control tb in tabPage2.Controls)
    {
        if (tb.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            data.Add(tb.Text);
    }
```

To read each textbox value in one list, each label value in another list, and then combine it to a dictionary, where the key is the label value and the value is the label value.

And then take the dictionary, and insert it inside an xml doc:

```
    String[] allKeys = null;
    allKeys = new String[data.Count];

    xmlDocs.Root.Add(
    new XElement("Profile", new XAttribute("Name", tbProfile.Text),
    allKeys.Select(x => new XElement(x, dictionary[x]))));
```

But it seems too complicated and long to me, and I wonder if there is another way

Comment: Seems quite short to me...

Comment: Why do you need this? The UI shouldn't be used to actually store the data; only display it... Create a model class with `Name`, `Age` etc. properties and bind the labels to their respective properties. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33(v=vs.90).aspx. Now, the class itself can be easily serialized into xml if you put right attributes on the properties. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx for more info.

Comment: By the way, why would you keep `each textbox value in one list, each label value in another list, and then combine it to a dictionary` instead of creating (and populating) a dictionary straight away?

Comment: @KonradMorawski, I am filling the xml with users input (textboxes), and I'm doing it separately because I couldn't figure out how to to it in one go. I tried different things but they didn't work.

Comment: @user990635 see the links I posted. If you can't get this approach working, post a question describing specific difficulties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a class, it would be easier. For example:

```
[Serializable]
public class Profile
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string NameAttribute { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Then define a `Profile` list top of your code (in class level,outside of your methods)

```
List<Profile> profiles = new List<Profile>();
```

When you want to add new `Profile`, for example in button click,create a new `Profile` instance and add it to your list:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    profiles.Add(new Profile
    {
        NameAttribute = txtProfile.Text,
        Name = txtName.Text,
        Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text),
        Country = txtCountry.Text
    });
}
```

Then when you want to save all Profiles into `XML` use `XmlSerializer`:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Profile>),new XmlRootAttribute("Profiles"));
    var fs = new FileStream("profiles.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    serializer.Serialize(fs,profiles);
}
```